# Every nontrivial subgroup $H$ of $S_9$ containing some odd permutation contains a transposition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

This is a true or false question. Apparently, it is false, but I don't follow.

Clearly, if it contains an odd permutation, and an even/odd permutation is defined by the number of transpositions it could be broken into, then every permutation is a set of transpositions. At least, that's what I had gotten out of it. Am I wrong? I'm very confused with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every permutation can be written as a *product* of transpositions (of not-necessarily-distinct elements); for instance, the permutation $(1\ 2\ 3)$ can be written as the product $(1\ 2)\cdot(2\ 3)$.  But that's not what the question is asking about.  It's asking whether the subgroup must contain some element of the form $(a\ b)$ (and note that $(a\ b)$ is an odd permutation), or whether there is a subgroup with some element being odd such that no such element is of that $(a\ b)$ form.  For instance, the subgroup $A_9\subset S_9$ has no transpositions in it, but since by definition $A_9$ has no odd elements at all, it doesn't disprove the claim.

To prove that the statement is false, all you have to do is exhibit some subgroup which has no such form.  A broad hint: can you find an odd element $s\in S_9$, not a transposition, such that $s^2=e$?  Then the subgroup $\langle s\rangle\subset S_9$ will be just $\{e,s\}$ and neither of these elements is a transposition...